# Google Docs / drive Comment and Tagging API

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api

Does anyone know if the Google Docs API supports commenting. I am trying to build an app that allows me to add comments and tagging to files on gdrive?

Thanks...

Any tips and or advice would be greatly appreciated!

-Ashley

Answer (score 0):

Comments are not exposed by the Documents List API, you might consider using the `<docs:description>` element to store application-specific tags.

Comment: Can we convince someone to expose it even if it isn't supported?

Comment: Not sure if we can "convince" someone but the PMs are already aware of this feature request

Comment: It is becoming a common practice to tag files using extended properties (in pc) and spotlight comments on the mac.   Unless this information is stored with the file, it will obviously be lost after a round trip to the drive.   This feature would be really valuable.